# Remove the [good-design] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design) sits on ~340 questions. Shall we extirpate it?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a meta tag to me. This is what we pay Trogdor for, right?

Comment: I'd like to upvote this multiple times just for extirpate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After realizing there was no corresponding [bad-design](/questions/tagged/bad-design) tag, I removed this - it isn't fair to all the folks looking for practices that result in inefficient and hard-to-maintain code.

[image: burninated]